# Linux--What program is responsible for the "Battery Low" notification, when I have plenty of battery left?

Tags: linux, laptop, battery, power

Using Linux, Devuan Release 4 chimaera (Debian derivative--non-systemd, parallel to Bullseye)

I have a Thinkpad x220 laptop. The battery has plenty of power.  I can keep the laptop on for a few hours, but I keep getting a pair of notifications popping up saying "Battery Low".

I would like to know:

1. Is there a way to know what process is triggering this message?
   a. If not, does anyone recognize or know what process is triggering it.
2. Why is it triggering when I have a charged battery?

See image below:

[image: battery low]

Answer (score 1):

That looks a lot like an `xmessage` window. You'll need to find the running xmessage process and check its *parent* PID to know what caused the message to be displayed. (Use htop, pstree, etc.)

In general, for most regular windows `xprop` should reveal the program name and (usually) the process ID.

Comment: pstree output = lightdm-+-lxsession-+-lxpanel-+-sh---xmessage

Comment: I tried "apt-get remove --purge gnome-power-manager powermgmt-base upower" but I am still getting the message, although now it's just one notification window.

Answer (score 1):

You're running lxde. So it will be a notifier/applet/panel app probably starting with "lx".

The linked image is pretty lowres though, so maybe an openbox thing.

Check your obconf (open box config)/ lx session config for something that rhymes with "battery"

As to why it happens...the threshold may be reading wrong, ie it's set at 80% but triggers at 80 full instead of 80% empty. Pure WAG as we don't know where it's coming from.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the power manager due to battery status 'flapping', see this:

[power manager notifications repeating incessantly ... power problems?](https://superuser.com/questions/1433936/power-manager-notifications-repeating-incessantly-power-problems)

I'm still looking for a nice solution to this...